# Solving This Particular Recurrence Equation

Tags: recurrence-relations

Let $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$. Is there any way I could solve this recurrence?
$$
  a_k=-\dfrac{\lambda^2 a_{k-4}}{k(k+1)}
$$
where
$$ 
  a_0\in\mathbb{R} \quad\quad
  a_1\in\mathbb{R} \quad\quad
  a_2=0 \quad\quad
  a_3=0
$$

Comment: What is $i$ in the denominator? Is that $\sqrt{-1}$ or the term index? I.e. do you want to solve $$a_k = -\frac{\lambda^2}{k(k+1)}a_{k-4}$$?

Comment: Ah, misread. Saw $j$ instead of $i$ in the denominator for no reason. Deleted my answer

Comment: $i$ is the index of the sequence. It could be as you say with the $k$, uranix.

Paul, I was thinking I had forgotten something.

Answer (score 2):

Your sequence actually splits into four distict sequences. Let $i = 4k + l$ where $l = 0, 1, 2, 3$.
$$
a_{i} = -\frac{\lambda^2}{i(i+1)} a_{i-4}\\
a_{4k+l} = -\frac{\lambda^2}{(4k+l)(4k+l+1)} a_{4(k-1)+l} = \\ =
\frac{\lambda^4}{(4k+l-4)(4k+l-3)(4k+l)(4k+l+1)} a_{4(k-2)+l} =
\dots\\\dots = \frac{(-\lambda^2)^k}{\prod_{m=1}^k(4m+l)\cdot\prod_{m=1}^k(4m+1)} a_l =
\frac{(-\lambda^2)^k}{16^k\prod_{m=1}^k\left(m+\frac{l}{4}\right)\cdot\prod_{m=1}^k\left(m+\frac{l+1}{4}\right)} a_l = \\ =
\frac{(-\lambda^2)^k}{16^k\left(k+\frac{l}{4}\right)_k\cdot\left(k+\frac{l+1}{4}\right)_k} a_l
$$
where $(a)_k = a(a-1)\dots(a-k+1)$ is Pochhammer symbol.